Why isn't AWS Chime throttling behaviour per-channel like the docs say it should be?
I have 3 AWS Chime channels in an app instance. If I try to quickly make 14 list-channel-memberships requests of one of them, it succeeds.
But if I simultaneously do this for 3 different channels, sending 14 list-channel-memberships commands to each, it fails with errors like this:
An error occurred (ThrottledClientException) when calling the ListChannelMemberships operation: The throttling limit has been exceeded.

But according to the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/chime-sdk.html#chm-sdk-messaging-quotas), "Rate of ListChannelMemberships, ListChannelBans, ListChannelModerators requests" is throttled to "15 requests per second per Channel and Elastic Channel".
Why should making requests to multiple channels at once cause throttling if the quota is on a per-channel basis?
Is this covered by some other quota? I looked through the docs but couldn't find any others which looked applicable.
Here's my code:
for i in {1..14}; do
    # channels variable is an array containing 1 or 3 channel names
    for channel in $channels; do
        # ampersand at end of this line means don't wait for command to finish before continuing loop
        echo aws chime-sdk-messaging list-channel-memberships --chime-bearer $chimebearer --region eu-central-1 --channel-arn $channel > /dev/null &
    done
done

